# Search pattern not unique? - Regular expression

Tags: python, string, pandas, search

I want to write a function to clean the index column of the dataframe.

1. Delete the whole row that has high-level IDs. For example, delete

   `East Kootenay (5901)   01010`
2. Tailor the index into 7-digit number for low-level IDs. For example, turn

   `East Kootenay A (5901017) RDA 02020`
   into `5901017`
3. If it has two parenthesis keep only the 7-digit number in the second parenthesis. For example,

   `Sechelt (Part) (5929803) IGD 02020` to `5929803`

   `Capital H (Part 1) (5917054) RDA 01020` to `5917054`

   `Capital H (Part 2) (5917056) RDA 02030` to `5917056`

   `T'Sou-ke 1 (Sooke 1) (5917817) IRI 01010` to `5917817`

   `T'Sou-ke 2 (Sooke 2) (5917818) IRI 00000` to `5917818`

An example of code only works for one bracket is

```
def extract_id(s):
    m = re.search('\((.*)\)', s)
    if m:
        i = int(m.group(0)[1:-1])
        return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Read data
    census_subdivision_profile = pd.read_excel('../data/census_subdivision_profile.xlsx', sheetname='Data',
                                               index_col='Geography', encoding='utf-8').T
    print(census_subdivision_profile.head())
    print(census_subdivision_profile.shape)

    census_subdivision_profile.index = census_subdivision_profile.index.map(extract_id)
    print(census_subdivision_profile.index)
```

To see the full code, see another question I posted earlier

[Merge dataframes that have indices that one contains another (but not the same)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754881/merge-dataframes-that-have-indices-that-one-contains-another-but-not-the-same/44755753?noredirect=1#comment76543168_44755753)

Comment: I guess you wrote `[1:-1]` with the intention of stripping the brackets off the digits but your regex doesn't actually capture the brackets so you're just stripping off the first and last digits there.

Comment: A correct tag is half an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you intended `'\(([^)]*)\)'` ... hth

Comment: See purpose 1 delete the row?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the distinction between points 2 and 3. In both cases you're just wanting to extract the 7 digit number in brackets? In that case I'd be more explicit with the regex, like `\((\d{7})\)`

Comment: It's the same as the code you already showed, just use this regex instead of yours.

Comment: It's not actually working because it acts on the indices and return `Index([None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
       ...
       None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
      dtype='object', length=533)`

Comment: Well that's a different question. I'm not familiar with `pd.read_excel()`. You asked about regular expressions so I gave an answer that will extract the value you want from the example strings given.

Comment: Ok now it's working but it contains NaN, therefore it's not dropping the invalid indices.

Comment: See purpose 1 delete the row?